# how to integrate a horizontal scroll view in master detail template in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I integrate a horizontal scroll view in a fragment on the master flow flow in android ?
The point is to have multiple forms in one section and to switch horizontally between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :
On the fragment and on the `OnCreateView` method we add this code :

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter1(getFragmentManager());


        new setAdapterTask().execute();
```

After that, we add a class for the `adapterTask`

```
private class setAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                       mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
    }
```

And that's it ! Hope it will help someone